# can't figure out why neither javascript or jquery work on web server

Tags: javascript, jquery

new member here, i've been reading a lot on this website but haven't really needed much help till now...
for a couple of days i've been frying my brain...can't work it out, note that i'm a semi-noob here's my problem:

first time building a website, www.morningmood.org , i can't get javascript to work properly, it kind of works when it wants to... i'm talking about simple things, not complicated code prone to error, i can't even get a proper console log message, i've tried pretty much everything i found on here...won't work.
another weird thing, at the moment my js file included, has just a simple console log message, but on the website itself ,shows a script that i had a few days ago, a button when clicked that shows a message..

here's the head

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <title>Morning Mood</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
 <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/myScript.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
</head>
```

any thoughts? i could really use some help... thanks!

[main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utwhl.png)

Comment: What is stored in `jq.js`? Does the jquery file exists on your server?

Comment: Open your console and check the error **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** - if you go inside the folder `scripts/` you will see that you're missing the `jq.js` file

Comment: Is the scripts folder in the root of your website/project? Else try to make your path like this:
<script src="../scripts/jq.js"></script>

Comment: that was fast, i was just messing around with it, myScript is the file, now it has a whole new error...

Comment: the scripts folder is in the same place as the index file(root?)

Comment: fixed the path and the file name...any thoughts now? thanks guys :)

Comment: Look under the 'console' tab, are any errors or warnings displayed when the page loads? Now that the resources are loading we need to look at if the logic is executing correctly.

Comment: jquery-3.1.1.js:9425 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9425
ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9143
displayContent @ myScript.js:5
(anonymous) @ myScript.js:2
mightThrow @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3570
process @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3638
jquery-3.1.1.js:3636 [Violation] Handler took 193ms of runtime (50ms allowed)

Comment: and the myScript.js has a console.log("hello"); command

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not "hello", it's "hellouz", because that's what's logging when I visit your site.

Comment: Your script is clearly `console.log('hellouz');`. Here it is http://www.morningmood.org/scripts/myScript.js!

Comment: it is a message, not important what's the message, but i can't see that in my console in chrome, and ibrahim, that was an old file that i had and i couldn't get it to work...how did u see that, is not on the server....wth is going on :))

Comment: ok... so i'm really lost, i have a weird error on the body of the page, a script that ran a few days ago(not on the server), in the console i get the errors i posted(not hellouz as i concole  logged it:) ), and ibrahim pointed to a script that isn't there...what am i doing wrong???

Comment: also added a pic if it helps, i could do only 1...

Comment: if you're using chrome, try ctrl+shift+r to reload all assets instead of the ones from the browser's cache. it might help

Comment: thanks :) well that really helped. can you also tell me why that happened?